# HAML submit form in rails link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a small search form written in HAML in my rails application, here is the code:

```
= search_form_for @q do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :first_name_cont, "Name Contains"
    = f.text_field :first_name_cont
  = f.button :submit, "Search"
```

I want something like a link_to for the submit action so that it knows what controller action to call, how can I do that in HAML? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a HAML guru, but `form_for`, and likely Ransack's `search_form_for` have a `submit` method on the block object to make a submit button. Therefore, that last line should resemble `= f.submit "Search"`

Comment: this would output an input type["submit"] and not an <a> tag however. other option would be to use jQuery and submit the form when clicked on the <a> tag

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your question, but it looks like you're using Ransack. According to their documentation, If you are trying to send the form to a particular route, you can set the `:url` option in your `form_for` line. You don't have to modify the submit button at all.

For example:

```
= search_form_for @q, :url => your_controller_action_path do |f|
   ... # The rest of your code
```